# compile c file from outside of workspace

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

I have a c file that it's located in the folder /my_test as shown below. I can run the command below successfully if I'm located on the "my_test" directory.

```
~/my_test$ strace -e write -f gcc -I/home/user/my_test/headers -fsyntax-only mymainfile.c
```

is it possible to run the same command from a different directory? Let's say I'm in /home/user/new_test instead.

```
~/new_test$ strace -e write -f gcc -I/home/user/my_test/headers -fsyntax-only -I/home/user/my_test/mymainfile.c
```

I believe the "-I" flag only works for header files only correct? is there an equivalent flag for the c file?

Comment: Uh, just drop the `-I` before the path to the .c file.

Comment: ah lol, I tried that but it didn't work before. Maybe I miss typed something. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-I` mean adding extras headers path, the same thing for `-L` but for precompiled objects (libraries).

So you need to remove `-I` you did, the command should be like this:

`~/new_test$ strace -e write -f gcc -I/home/user/my_test/headers -fsyntax-only /home/user/my_test/mymainfile.c`